# Will ferric nitrate or nitric acid dissolve polylactic acid?

Tags: solubility

Will ferric nitrate dissolve 3D printed items? I wish to etch some sterling silver, for which we use either ferric nitrate or nitric acid, and wonder about 3d printing the design straight onto the silver to form the block against the acid.

Comment: Hi Julie, welcome to Chem.SE! Please take the [tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with our site. Thanks! Btw, your question title does not match the content? Were you trying to dissolve polyacetic acid or 3D printed items?

Comment: @Gaurang That's because PLA(polylactic acid) is used in 3D printing. I did a project on that.